# Quartus II: Customise compiler messages

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

I am working with the Altera Quartus II compiler for my Cyclone IV. I am not happy with what is considered `Info`, `Warning`, `Error`, etc.

For example, inferred latches are `Info`, but I want them as `Warning`. Parallel compilation disabled is a `Warning`, but I want it as an `Info`.

Is there a way to customise the compiler messages in Quartus II?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Quartus II 32-bit Version 12.0 Build 263 SJ Web Edition (Service pack 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the same question to Xilinx. They suggested writing a script to search through the INFO messages for what I was looking for. For example

```
grep "INFO: inferred latches" fpga.syr
```

Answer (score 3):

I asked Altera support with a service request and they replied:

"We do not have this kind of option, you may hide the message but you could not change the level of the message."

So no official way, but maybe someone else knows of a hack.

Comment: I'd be interested in hiding messages also! How can you do that?

Comment: I think it's something like // altera message_off 10000  Where you replace 10000 with the error number but let me ask.

Comment: @Randomblue You can right-click the message and select "Suppress". You can set up rules to suppress similar messages with the "Message Suppression Manager". These apply to particular projects, but you can export your rules from one project and import them into another.

Comment: Littleman is right, that's the same thing Altera said.